# Omit attribute when fact is not defined

Tags: ansible

I've currently many of this tasks. The file module here is just an example.

```yaml
- file:
    path: "{{ datapath }}"
    state: "directory"
  when:
    - "storage is not defined"

- file:
    path: "{{ datapath }}"
    state: "directory"
  delegate_to: "{{ storage.host }}"
  when:
    - "storage is defined"
    - "storage.host is defined"
```

Which either creates a directory on the inventory_host or on a different host, when the fact is defined.

I wonder, if it is possible to reduce the number of tasks here. Normally I would use the `omit` filter. But because I've several conditions, I'm not sure what kind of syntax to use here for `delegate_to`.

Comment: Because you have two conditions with an `and` you do have three cases: when storage is not defined, when storage is defined and the host is defined, but you are not addressing what to do when storage is defined but not the host? What should happen in this specific case?

Comment: I asume that when the dict `storage` is defined, it always contains `host` element. Of course I could also check that, but for the example here, it is ok. I've learned that Ansible throws an error when you only check for `storage.host is defined` without checking first, if `storage is defined`. The implicit check is not done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use the `omit` special variable in an [inline expression](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.1.x/templates/#if-expression)

```yaml
- file:
    path: "{{ datapath }}"
    state: directory
  delegate_to: "{{ storage.host if storage.host is defined else omit }}"
```

With this, and because you can chain inline-if's, then you could have multiple conditions that ends in an `omit`, e.g.

```yaml
delegate_to: >-
  {{
    storage.host
      if storage.host is defined
      else 'localhost'
        if for_localhost | default(false)
        else omit
  }}
```

Would be:

- delegated to `storage.host` when defined
- delegated to `localhost` when `for_localhost` is truthy
- omitted, otherwise

Comment: Ah, inline expression was the hint, I didn't know about. Thanks